# Dynamic Product in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dynamic product using Pandas. I can explain this better using an example given below. This is the table I have:

```
Company  Year   Value
A        1990   1
A        1991   2
A        1992   3
A        1993   4
B        1990   5
B        1991   6
B        1992   7
B        1993   8
```

I want to create an additional column that is a product of the column 'value' [in a Company wise manner] to get an output like below:

```
Company  Year   Value  Product
A        1990   1      1 
A        1991   2      2 
A        1992   3      6
A        1993   4      24
B        1990   5      5
B        1991   6      30
B        1992   7      210
B        1993   8      1680
```

I have tried everything from using lamda function, cumprod, etc. Please can someone help me out with this?

Comment: So you want a *cummulative* product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby` + [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumprod.html):

```
In [6]: df['Product'] = df.groupby('Company')['Value'].cumprod()

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
  Company  Year  Value  Product
0       A  1990      1        1
1       A  1991      2        2
2       A  1992      3        6
3       A  1993      4       24
4       B  1990      5        5
5       B  1991      6       30
6       B  1992      7      210
7       B  1993      8     1680
```

Comment: OMG. This was so simple. Why didn't I think of this before? It works! Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: @GauthamKanthasamy, glad i could help :)